# When you press the Path button, it becomes unresponsive

Tags: python

Pressing the "PATH " button will open a new window and put you in an unresponsive state.

I can't attach a file because I don't know how to do it.

The OpenTest.xlsx file is required to perform the program. It should have the Test and Program sheets. You can do this by randomly creating the file and sheet.

Here's the source content

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import openpyxl
import os
import time
import subprocess
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto.timings import TimeoutError
import win32api


def set_path():
 folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
 if folder_path:
  windows_path = os.path.abspath(folder_path)
  ws['C2'] = windows_path
  wb.save('OpenTest.xlsx')
  path_label.config(text=windows_path)
 else:
  path_label.config(text="Route setting has been cancelled.")

  print("AAA")

def create_path_dialog():
 path_dialog = tk.Toplevel(root)
 path_dialog.title("PATH")
 folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
 if folder_path:
  windows_path = os.path.abspath(folder_path)
  ws['C2'] = windows_path
  wb.save('OpenTest.xlsx')
  path_label.config(text=windows_path)
 else:
  path_label.config(text="Route setting has been cancelled.")
 path_dialog.destroy()





root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Open Test")
root.geometry("640x300")  


button = tk.Button(root, text="PATH : ", command=create_path_dialog)

button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")  


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('OpenTest.xlsx')
ws = wb["Test"]
wss = wb["Program"]

path_label = tk.Label(root, text=ws['C2'].value if ws['C2'].value else "Path not set. Set your route...")
path_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")  

root.deiconify()

root.mainloop()
```

1. A new window should pop up.
2. The new window should bring up the file dialog and allow you to set the path.